# Cherry-picking with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following:

```
<xml>
    <cls>
        <cl id="foo">
            <a>1</a>
            <b>1</b>
        </cl>
        <cl id="bar">
            <a>4</a>
            <b>2</b>
        </cl>
        <cl id="foo">
            <a>1</a>
            <b>3</b>
        </cl>
    </cls>
    <orgs>
        <org clid="foo">
        </org>
        <org clid="foo">
        </org>
        <org clid="bar">
        </org>
        <org clid="bar">
        </org>
        <org clid="foo">
        </org>
    </orgs>
</xml>
```

How can I select the `xml/orgs/org`s where org's `clid` matches one in `xml/cls/cl` (by its `id` attribute) where `cl/a`'s value is 1?

It's a bit complex, and I don't see how I can deal with relations like that.

Compatibility with XPath 1.0 would be prefered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: 
`org` where `clid` equal to `id` in `cl` that has `a = 1` child

```
 //xml/orgs/org[@clid = //xml/cls/cl[a=1]/@id]
```

or if you don't want to keep `xml`, `org` and `cls` tags and make it shorter (but better keep original one if your xml is big/complex):

```
//org[@clid = //cl[a=1]/@id]
```

Comment: Thank you, I modified it slightly:
`xml/orgs/org[@clid=/xml/cls/cl[a/.=1]/@id]`

Answer (score 1):

**`xpath`** expression:

```
//orgs/org[@clid=preceding::cls/cl[a=1]/@id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (XPath 1.0 expression) :

```
xmllint --xpath '//orgs/org[@clid=string(//cls/cl/a[text()="1"]/ancestor::cl[1]/@id)]' file.xml
```

Output :

```
<org clid="foo">
</org><org clid="foo">
</org><org clid="foo">
```

Comments :

I fetch the `id` string dynamically

Answer (score 0):

This XPath 1.0 expression,

```
//orgs/org[@clid=//cl[a=1]/@id]
```

will select all `org` elements with `@clid` attribute value equal to the `@id` attribute value of at least one `cl` element with a child `a` element with value of `1`, as requested:

```
<org clid="foo">
        </org>
<org clid="foo">
        </org>
<org clid="foo">
        </org>
```